# Doing T-test across two data sets

Tags: t-test, structural-equation-modeling, cross-section

So our paper is undergoing a second round of reviews and one of the reviewers asked the following question:

"Add a t-test for wave 1 vs. wave 2. They won't be perfect, but if they are included as controls (are they?), that's fine. I saw the acknowledgement at the end, and so long as they are in some model as controls, this doesn't worry me."

We are very confused as to what the reviewer meant...

A little background to the study: it has two cross-sectional surveys collected at two points in time using the same variables. We have two SEM models with all the main constructs as well as all the control variables (demographics, etc.) included in the SEM, one for each wave of the survey. We were trying to see if there's any changes in the two models in terms of relationships between the main constructs. We know this is not perfect since it's not panel data, and we acknowledged it in the limitations. But we are not intending to test statistical differences anyway.

Is the reviewer suggesting a t-test across the two data sets? Is this even possible? Or maybe is the reviewer suggesting something completely different? Any insights/suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Without more context as to the data and purpose of your paper, we probably are not in as good a position as you to try to make sense of the reviewer's comment. // If you are being asked to do a t test for which assumptions are not met, then you might mention to the journal editor that you feel uncomfortable doing that. Maybe a better question for 'Academia' site. but clearly stating in plain English what your reservations are (omitting there mysterious technical details about 'SEM', etc.).

Comment: Yes I think I might do that. I just don't know if it's a kind of statistic that I never heard of. But thanks for the suggestions!!